# What does it mean for a phase to be unstable due to quantum fluctuations?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter

Generally in the literature on quantum critical phenomena (as opposed to ordinary critical phenomena in statistical mechanics), there is the idea that quantum fluctuations can prevent ordering of a phase. My very basic question is: **formally speaking, what does it mean for a phase to be unstable (or melted) due to quantum fluctuations?** I want to emphasize that I am looking for a formal definition that isn't tied to a specific model Hamiltonian.

I have seen this idea discussed in the case of the Heisenberg antiferromagnet in 1D, where the classical antiferromagnet state (all spins alternating spin up and down) is unstable towards the creation of domains. One way I hear people describe this is that the "quantum spin fluctuations melte the classical antiferromagnet phase", but that seems odd to me, because I can't really put my finger on how this idea generalizes. Is it the fact that spin is a non-commuting operator that is important here? Otherwise what makes this destruction by "quantum fluctuations" as opposed to a phase destroyed by classical fluctuations? After all, you could say similar things about classical spins not ordering in the 1D Ising model due to spin fluctuations, right?

For example, one may look at the following links where the author(s) all use language suggesting that "quantum fluctuations" prevent ordering of a system in various ways:

Example 1: [Antiferromagnetism](https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys1715)

Example 2: [Quantum Paraelectricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_paraelectricity)

Example 3: [Quantum Pendulum](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.2121)

Comment: Just a comment on the distinction between classical and quantum fluctuations: classical fluctuations are a finite temperature effect, whereas quantum fluctuations are relevant even at $T=0$. So if we want to discuss a transition between distinct many-body ground states, we must invoke quantum fluctuations.

Comment: Thank you d_b, I have heard that statement before but have found it confusing and perhaps it's at the core of my question. At T=0 you are presumably in a stationary eigenstate of the system, so how does it make sense to discuss "quantum fluctuations" if nothing is fluctuating? For comparison in the classical state you truly are looking at an ensemble that is fluctuating, so it makes sense to discuss classical fluctuations to me.

Comment: I'll try to give an appropriate answer later, but for now: take a look at Goldstone Bosons

Comment: well best way to understand this is following: assume you calculate functional average(VEV) of the phase in groundstate by perturbation theory. So if phase is classically ordered, it means that in lowest order VEV of phase is non zero, also you have long-range order of VEV of phase phase correlation. But if you want to add quantum fluctuations it means that you should add higher order terms. and in that case ODLRO will be destroyed. so VEV changes as you add higher order terms(quantum fluctuations)

Comment: @physshyp according to that definition that would mean that "quantum fluctuations" is a basis dependent phenomenon. So if I choose the right basis, there are no quantum fluctuations, is that right? If you have time I'd be interested if you could write up a full answer from your comment

Comment: no it is not basis dependent, what I mean is the following: take any lagrangian and solve equation of motion, the solution is you classical solutions. now you can add quantum fluctiations by Taylor expanding your lagrangian around that classical solution, the first order terms are classical solutions. higher order terms will be quantum fluctuations.

Comment: see page 93 of Wen's book

Comment: also if you do not know Quantum Field Theory, it is virtually impossible for you to understand the answer of your question. Stop thinking in terms of hamiltonian, think in terms of partition function and lagrangians. when you calculate any  average you use partition function. and if you use only first terms it is just classical, if you add more its quantum fluctuations.

Comment: @physshyp I used the language of Hamiltonians because that's what is mostly used in stat mech and non-relativistic QFT in condensed matter. I don't see why you would absolutely need a Lagrangian picture instead.

Comment: well in statistical mechanics what you call hamiltonian can be interpreted as action given that plancks constant is replaced with inverse temperature. The point is not whether you use lagrangian or hamiltonian, the point is whether you use functional or canonical quantization. this question is very easy to understand in functional quantization. Being a condensed matter physicist my self, I use functional integral picture pretty frequently to describe the systems. The examples you gave in question all can be represented by functional integral.

Comment: I mean zero temperature quanutm mechanical system, and finite tempreture ststistical system is same. if you understand latter you already know former just replace the word thermal fluctuation with quantum fluc. and plancks constant with temperature. and 0 temperature solution with classical solution.

Answer (score 5):

I will give a partial answer. Assume we have a system with Lagrangian density of
$\mathcal{L}(\phi,\partial_\mu\phi)$
EOM is (this is just Euler-Lagrange equations, there is no quantum mechanics so far)
$$\frac{\delta}{\delta\phi}\mathcal{L}\bigg|_{\phi=\phi_{cl}}=0$$
Where $\phi_{cl}$ is classical solution. Now assume you want to calculate VEV of $\phi$

$$\langle\phi\rangle=Z^{-1}\int\mathcal{D}\phi \phi\exp\bigg(i\int d^dx\mathcal{L}(\phi,\partial_\mu\phi)\bigg)$$
now we want to see the influence of quantum fluctuations to classical solution. We can make the integral substitution
$$\phi\to\bar{\phi}+\phi_{cl}$$
so we have
$$\langle\phi\rangle=Z^{-1}\int\mathcal{D}\bar{\phi} (\phi_{cl}+\bar{\phi})\exp\bigg(i\int d^dx\mathcal{L}(\phi_{cl}+\bar{\phi},\partial_\mu(\phi_{cl}+\bar{\phi}))\bigg)$$
now we can write this as
$$\langle\phi\rangle=\phi_{cl}+ Z^{-1}\int\mathcal{D}\bar{\phi} (\bar{\phi})\exp\bigg(i\int d^dx\mathcal{L}(\phi_{cl}+\bar{\phi},\partial_\mu(\phi_{cl}+\bar{\phi}))\bigg)$$

Ok now the first term is just the solution of the *classical* equation of motion so it is the classical solution, the second term is a functional average of all possible field configurations so it is a quantum mechanical object which includes the quantum fluctuations.
In other words the first term is the classical solution, and the second is quantum fluctuations.

So this is the general principle behind how quantum fluctuations change the classical solutions. You can play the same game while calculating any kind of average.

And in general including quantum fluctuations on top of classical solution just as I did, may break order. For example in $1+1$ dimensional $XY$ model, quantum fluctuations destroy long range order and reduce it to algebraic order. You can find this calculation on page 93 of Wen's QFT book. He exactly does what I did here, by first writing full theory and expanding it around the classical solution he shows that even if first terms have long range order by adding higher terms this reduces to algebraic order!

Comment: So would you say that speaking of "quantum fluctuations" automatically indicates a perturbative-type picture? Is there any meaning for the phrase "quantum fluctuations" in the context of non-perturbative theories of materials (no Feynman diagrams etc.)?

Comment: I ask because there are cases in experiment on materials where it is unclear what the starting point for the classical solution should be. In that case, it appears from your answer that what qualifies as "quantum fluctuations" will depend very much on what ground state you pick to do perturbation theory around. Do you agree with that statement?

Comment: by perturbative if you mean expansion around the classical solution, I would say yes, by definition quantum fluctuation is the perturbation away from the classical solution due to quantum mechanics. about your last equation, the answer is no. it does not depend any choice. quantum fluctuation is derivation from classical solution(Newton).

Comment: also if you know statistical physics so well, just replace temperature with plancks constant. in statistical system thermal fluctuation is as same as, a quantum fluctuation in quantum system.i mean in statistical system if you increase temperature. the system will be different than 0 temperature system.  now it is same anagly in quantum but instead of temperature you have plancks constants. and what you call classical solution corresponds to case for zero plancks constant.

Comment: @KFGauss btw this kind of reasoning is only applicable for bosons. For fermions it is different.

Comment: My point is that the ground state and associated Hamiltonian/Lagrangian you choose to approximate a system with are not uniquely defined, especially in real life where theory is difficult to do accurately. In that case, your answer implies what qualifies as quantum fluctuations (i.e. perturbative corrections) depends on your starting point.

Comment: You should take a qm course.

Comment: if we are giving uninvited and dismissive recommendations to each other, then I recommend you take an English reading comprehension course. I gave taken QM, stat mech, and QFT. But I was unsatisfied with the vagueness of the term quantum fluctuations. It seems from your answer anything beyond the classical solution qualifies. I am just pointing out that in the context of experimental physics you don't always know the classical solution you should start out with, hence the ambiguity.

Comment: well let me explain it like this, equation of motion is well defined it is not sth you choose, so any behavior different than the EOM says is due to quantum fluctuations.   nothing in my argument is basis dependent, or I never choose anything, I just calculated an average of $\phi$ since it is an average it is basis independent, and subtracted the solution of EOM from it. and what I call quantum fluctuation is this difference. there is not a choice whatsoever I nthis  treatment. the fact that you still not getting this is remarkable.

Comment: You clearly have a lot to learn and do not understand QM/condensed matter in real life, so I will end our discussion like this. If I give you a piece of SrTiO$_3$ can you tell me what the EOM is? No, you definitely can't. You try an approximate Lagrangian/Hamiltonian/etc. to describe the material, but your answer differs with that of another person who will obtain a different EOM and therefore different quantum fluctuations. The point is that quantum fluct. aren't a unique observable in experiment, *because* you need a reference EOM. "That you are still not getting this is remarkable."

Comment: Notice that I didn't say anything about basis, you are referring to my comment before you wrote your answer.

Comment: what you say is completely irrelevant, and does not make sense, it is like saying: newtons equations are not unique because there are some complicated systems in real life that are hard to solve with newtons equations so we have to make an approximation to those systems, thus classical physics does not give unique experimental observables.  does not make sense at all.

Answer (score 3):

Yes (in addition to the other answers), the point is that if multiple terms in the Hamiltonian don't commute with one another, the ground state of the total Hamiltonian is no longer the same as the ground state of each individual term; and therefore can no longer qualify as a 'phase' in the traditional sense.
To speak of a 'phase', you (generally) want a many-body state that

- Is robust to small decoherence, i.e. you can look at a macroscopic 'order parameter' that makes classical sense.
- Does not manifestly change in time

The clearest example is perhaps crystallization of atoms. The Hamiltonian consists of a Lennart-Jones-like potential $\sum_{ij}V(\hat{r}_i-\hat{r}_j)$ , and a kinetic part $\sum_i \frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m}$. If this were a classical system, we could just treat $r_i$ and $p_i$ as classical numbers and minimize these terms separately. The first one results in the formation of a periodic lattice, the second one confirms that they all stand still, and there you have the ground state.
However, you cannot do this, because $\hat{r_i}$ and $\hat{p}_i$ are in fact conjugate operators, and according to quantum mechanics, they don't share a ground state. Now of course, the total Hamiltonian will still have a ground state, but it is not so clearly interpretable. The result is that atoms 'keep wiggling' according to QM, even at zero temperature (where everything is in the ground state). For some elements, such as Helium, these 'fluctuations' even prevent the proper formation of a solid phase in a natural setting.

A more general way to phrase this is that the quantum harmonic oscillator, unlike the classical one, must have an energy of at least 1/2. The question is then for each system, is this zero-point energy small enough to maintain macroscopic order?

For another perspective, the introductionary chapter of [Quantum Noise](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540223016) may be relevant.

Note: as LorenzMayer has reminded me in the comments, also in a classical system can it be that the ground state doesn't minimize all Hamiltonian terms separately (frustrated systems). However, the point here is rather that for a given system, quantumness makes things worse than for the classical limit and as such can let systems reach a tipping point where order is destroyed.

Comment: Even for classical systems it is viable that we cannot find the ground state by minimizing each term in the Hamiltonian separately, namely in frustrated systems.

Comment: @LorenzMayer good point; however I think 'quantum fluctuation' is a semiclassical term that specifically refers to cases where things change in comparison to the classical limit

Answer (score 1):

The mandatory reference for such issues is Sachdev's Quantum Phase Transitions. There, consulting the 2nd edition, page 7, we read:

"We note that phase transitions in classical models are driven only by thermal fluctuations,
as classical systems usually freeze into a fluctuationless ground state at T = 0. In contrast,
quantum systems have fluctuations driven by the Heisenberg uncertainty principle even in
the ground state, and these can drive interesting phase transitions at T = 0."

Fluctuations are important in critical systems. One of the fundamental aspects of criticality is the **null gap**, that is, the first excited energy (or energies, as is most common) is accessible by a vanishingly small ammount of energy that usually scales as 1/L, where L is a characteristic length or area or volume, you get it.

At page 8 he gives a really nice example:

"The low-lying magnetic excitations of the insulator LiHoF4 consist of fluctuations of the Ho ions between two spin states that are aligned parallel and antiparallel to a particular crystalline axis. These states can be represented by a two-state “Ising” spin variable on each Ho ion. At T = 0, the magnetic dipolar interactions between the Ho ions cause all the Ising spins to align in the same orientation, and so the ground state is a ferromagnet.Bitko, Rosenbaum, and Aeppli [49] placed this material in a magnetic field transverse to the magnetic axis. Such a field induces quantum tunneling between the two states of each Ho ion, and a sufficiently strong tunneling rate can eventually destroy the long-range magnetic order. Such a quantum phase transition was indeed observed"

The reference is Phys. Rev. Lett. 77, 940.

So what about [Goldstone Bosons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldstone_boson#Goldstone%27s_argument)? Well, remember the Landau idea of spontaneous symmetry breaking? We can reason (approximately) as Goldstone and Nambu themselves did (reversing the arrow of time, if you like, in the previous example of Sachdev):

1. We have a continuous symmetry (the ground state is not unique)
2. Act with the charge operator
3. Either we kill the vacuum or not.
4. If we don't, then a zero frequency mode lives
5. Infinite wavelength, likely means long-range order.
6. Here, [dimension considerations are essential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mermin%E2%80%93Wagner_theorem). Let us assume we are above the critical dimension.
7. Long-range correlations are one of the ingredients to set the party on fire
8. Let [Heisenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) enter the game and just wait (=

Comment: I don't see how this answers my question, your answer presupposes a definition of Quantum fluctuations, but never goes into formality defining what they actually are. I also don't see why you brought in Goldstone bosons prematurely.

Comment: To give an example of why I found the description from Sachdev's book confusing, it is a basic result of quantum theory that Heisenberg's uncertainty principle in no way implies quantum systems are fluctuating (rather the very opposite!). After all, even stationary eigenstates obey the uncertainty principle and they certainly aren't fluctuating in any sense. Clearly there is more to it than just the HUP.